# BlazeDS,GraniteDS, LiveCycleDS, WebOrb for Java which gives best performance?

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, amf

Does anyone have experiance in a lot of these?

I'm not so intrested in the pdf creation part of LCDS.

Just for flex messaging which would give me the best performance?  As far as I know LCDS and WebOrb both do real time streaming is that correct?

Basically the question is which gives quickest response and which will allow for most client connected to a single servlet container.

Thanks

**Edit 1**
This may be clearer what I want. I'm looking to server at least 5000 clients with sub second response times with push messages, I'm trying to figure out which is the most scalable option, I've been quoted several million push messages a day. Obviously we can throw more servers at the problem I'm not convinced thats the most maintainable option.

Its not media streaming I'm looking for, but more event updates.  It must work without sticky sessions.

Comment: Your question appears to be subjective and is likely to be closed? - why?

Comment: All the messages should be sent to all your 5000 clients?

Comment: @Cornel Creanga no. Some clients my get 10/20K I guess. The spec Isn't too clear on that.

Comment: Take a look on LCDS benchmark published on Damon blog: http://dcooper.org/blog/client/index.cfm?mode=entry&entry=23AFFFB0-4E22-1671-5DE9B407B946CE4D. The stress tools are available for download.

Comment: Thanks for that Cornel Creanga this is very useful information on LCDS.

Comment: I voted to close b/c this is extremely subjective.  There are so many factors involved, it is an impossible question to answer.  The only way to know true performance is to build the same app in all technologies and test them, then compare results.  No projects I'm aware of have ever had that sort of budget.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LiveCycleDS & WebOrb are the only ones providing messaging using sockets through RTMP protocol. Note that in this case the clients are not connected to a servlet container, but to a dedicated server included in the product distribution (bypassing the servlet mechanism).
There are more messaging servers on the market, [Lightstreamer](http://www.lightstreamer.com) is one of them. Or Flash media server.

There are many more things to be taken into consideration when choosing a solution however (price, integration with various architectures (like DMZ) and frameworks, paid support, documentation, your relation with the sales representative etc).

Comment: +1 for good info; although I didn't know that Flash Media Server could be used for things other than media streaming.  This is a good answer to an impossible question.

Comment: @flextras it shouldn't be impossible. For instance long polling inherently limits the number of possible connected clients. A 3 second polling interval inherrently limits the response time to over 3 seconds. So it appears to me a streaming socket connection would allow more connections (to the same hardware). Especially in light of the comment link Cornel Creanga gave to the question. In fact if info on Web Orbs client connections was there I pretty sure theres an answer in the info already provided.